# how to select a decimal in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple flight plan helper for Microsoft Flight Simulator in Python and i'm trying to turn a number into time
EXAMPLE- if something equals more than 0.6 (hours) in decimals it would add a 1 and minus the 0.6

PROBLEM 2:
How do i restart the code after its finished a question?

APOLOGIES TO EVERYONE CONFUSED    :D

```
print 'Hello and Welcome to Flight planner Helper V1'
print '-'
question_1 = raw_input('time or fuel? ')
if question_1 == 'time':
    a = input('nautical miles ')
    b = input('average ground speed ')
    c = a / float(b)
    print c            # <--- PROBLEM 1
    print 'Hours'


elif question_1 == 'fuel':
    c = input('travel time ')
    d = input('fuel usage (in litres)')
    e = c * d
    f = input('number of engines ')
    g = e * f
    print '%s litres' % (g)    

else:
    print 'your not a pilot, your a emu'

CLOSE = input('Press ENTER to close')
```

Comment: *"if something equals more than 0.6 (hours) in decimals it would add a 1 and minus the 0.6"* - I'm unclear what you're saying here, `1 - 0.6 = 0.4` Is that actually what you want as a result?

Comment: "How do i restart the code after its finished a question?" Just wrap the whole thing into a `while True: [your code]` loop.

Comment: _"if something equals more than 0.6 (hours) in decimals it would add a 1 and minus the 0.6"_ - Do you mean you want to round the answer?

Comment: Its sorta hard to explain. The 1.0 = 1 HOUR and 0.6 = 60 MINUTES so if the decimal number goes over 0.6 (60 MINUTES) it would minus the 0.6 and add a 1 so it would become 1.0 (1 HOUR)

Answer (score 1):

If c is in hours you can do something like:

```
hours = int(c)
minutes = int((c - hours) * 60)
seconds = int((c - hours - minutes / 60.0) * 3600))
print "%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

To repeat your code just wrap it in a loop like

```
while (True):
    your code here
```

Or even better put your code into a function and just call the function from the loop.

Comment: Thx I owe you one    :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor bugs in your code, but it's easy to sort them out:

```
import math

while True:

    print 'Hello and Welcome to Flight planner Helper V1'
    print '-'
    question_1 = raw_input('time or fuel? ')
    if question_1 == 'time':
        a = input('nautical miles ')
        b = input('average ground speed ')
        c = float(a) / float(b)
        print math.ceil(c),            # <--- PROBLEM 1
        print 'Hours'


    elif question_1 == 'fuel':
        c = raw_input('travel time ')
        d = raw_input('fuel usage (in litres)')
        e = float(c) * float(d)
        f = raw_input('number of engines ')
        g = float(e) * float(f)
        print '%s litres' % (g)    

    else:
        print 'your not a pilot, your a emu'

    again = raw_input('New calculation? y/n ')
    if again != "y": break
```

What do you mean with 0.6? Do you want to round up? math.ceil() does this.

Comment: It's generally good practice to explain to the OP why you made your changes. If they already understood then they wouldn't need to ask a question and it's better to teach them than only solving the problem for them.

Comment: Its sorta hard to explain. The 1.0 = 1 HOUR    and 0.6 = 60 MINUTES so if the decimal number goes over 0.6 (60 MINUTES)  it would minus the 0.6 and add a 1 so it would become 1.0 (1 HOUR)

Comment: when i do some calculations say 190 nautical miles and 40 ground speed it says  5.0 hours instead of 5.15 hours (5 hours AND 15 minutes)....                           ALSO how does != and break work?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add some sort of loop to the code so it can keep going / 'restart'.

Try adding a 'while' loop.

```
while True
```

Or any while loop you need.

Comment: Thank you. I only started coding this year   :D